# In .NET (C#) is there any place/wiki/book where you can find runtime/cost/memory footprint analysis?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, big-o, memory-footprint

So, I've been using the .NET framework for a little while now. There have been many times when I'm calling some static function or an instance method of List<> where I wonder what the relative performance cost of these operations are. In this case, I was wondering how terrible the static method Enum.GetValues() is. Is there any place where I can figure out relatively the run time of a .NET operation? If not, how do you know which methods can safely be called often and which ones you should avoid? Will I just have to test every method with a timer (please God no..)? Or is this something I'm being overly concerned about?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: And just for the record, my assumption since this is a static method is that they have just made an array at compile time of the Enum, however they still probably need to give me a copy of that array which alone will take time... That's why I'm concerned.

Comment: This is certainly a nice article, but my question isn't really a "which is faster" and its true I'm not sure it will ever matter in this case. I was just curious if there was a place I could look. If nothing else, so I can try to be efficient along the way.

Comment: Be concerned when your program get performance problems. Until you cannot detect difference in performance by using/testing - do nothing

Comment: Please consider reading documentation too - most collection in .Net specify performance expectations like `List` you've mentioned: [List.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) "If Count is less than Capacity, this method is an O(1) operation...."

Comment: Thanks! I have read some of it, but there are still a number of methods with no O(?) notation or explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of variables (no pun intended) when looking at performance. I found the best way is to simply profile my own applications using third-party software. That gives me an idea of memory usage and efficiency but mainly for my needs in my environment.

Here are a couple (most have trials):

[Ants Performance Profiler by redgate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/)

[JustTrace by Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/memory-performance-profiler.aspx)

[dotTrace by JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/)

[dotMemory by JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/)

Comment: This is great. Thanks a bunch! I apparently have to wait for a timer to give you the thumbs up, but I appreciate it. - John